# Are (finite dimensional?) inner product spaces also super vector spaces?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, inner-products

I recently read a little about super vector spaces and naturally I have a question and I don't know if I'm correct or if there's something in the definition that I don't quite understand.

My understanding is that a super vector space is a $\mathbb{Z}_2$-graded vector space, that is a vector space $V$ such that $V=V_0\oplus V_1$, $0,1\in \mathbb{Z}_2$  and $\forall x \in V_i$ we denote the parity of $x$ by $\left|x\right|=i$ (so $x\in V_0$ has parity $0$ and $x\in V_1$ has parity $1$).

Also, given a finite dimensional inner product space $(V,\langle\cdot,\cdot \rangle)$, and a subspace $F$ we can construct the subspace $$F^{\perp}=\left\lbrace u \in V, \langle u,v \rangle =0, v\in F\right\rbrace,$$ the subspace orthogonal to $F$. Furthermore, one can readily show that $V=F\oplus F^\perp$. (Not sure if the same can be said about infinite dimensional?). So call $F=V_0$ and $F^\perp=V_1$ then we can make $(V,\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle)$ into a super vector space by fixing a subspace $F$, and viewing $V$ as the direct sum of $F$ and $F^\perp$ and saying that if $x\in F, \left|x\right|=0$ and if $x\in F^\perp$ then $\left|x\right|=1$.

So is it correct to say that any finite dimensional inner product space can be made into a super vector space ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting my comments into an answer: any vector space $V$ can be made into a super vector space in many different ways, corresponding to any direct sum decomposition $V \cong V_0 \oplus V_1$. This is extra structure in general so it doesn't make sense to say that $V$ "is" a super vector space this way, only that it "can be made" a super vector space this way.

There are two canonical such decompositions, namely $V_0 = V$ (concentrated in even degree) or $V_1 = V$ (concentrated in odd degree). The even one is distinguished because that construction is [symmetric monoidal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_monoidal_category).

The category of super vector spaces is not that interesting, and equivalent to the category of pairs of vector spaces. What is interesting is the *symmetric monoidal category* of super vector spaces, which is where you define [supercommutative algebras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supercommutative_algebra) and [Lie superalgebras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_superalgebra) and so forth.